Casting Class to Interface using Generics
I have a bit of a complex data structure as below where templates were used extensively.
public interface ISensorDataModel
{
    bool IsHealthy { get; }
}

public interface ISensor : ISensorDataModel
{
    SensorDataModel GetDataModel();
    int StatueCode { get; }
    void DoSomeWork();
}

public interface IHubDataModel<T> : where T : ISensorDataModel
{
    List<T>? Sensors { get; }
}

public interface IHub<T> : IHubDataModel<T> where T : ISensor
{        
    bool IsOk { get; }
    IHubDataModel<T> GetDataModel();
}

public class SensorDataModel : ISensorDataModel
{
    public bool IsHealthy { get; set; }
}

public class Sensor : SensorDataModel, ISensor
{
    public int StatueCode { get; set; }
    public void DoSomeWork() {}
    public SensorDataModel GetDataModel() => return new SensorDataModel(this);
}

public class Hub : HubDataModel<Sensor>, IHub<Sensor>
{
    bool IsOk { get; set; }
    public IHubDataModel<Sensor> GetDataModel() => new HubDataModel<Sensor>(this);
}

I need to cast Hub object to IHubDataModel<ISensorDataModel> and apparently implicit casting doesn't work,
I wonder how I can perform the following casts.
Hub => IHubDataModel<ISensorDataModel>
IHubDataModel<Sensor> => IHubDataModel<ISensorDataModel>


When you finish this affair so complex you had to call on Others to help fix it, what fabulous advantage will it confer such that the pain of passing it on to the next person is forgiven?

The code you showed doesn't even compile.
